# How to deal with same user with multiple role type

Tags: php, mysqli

Am building a system with the following type of account in order of hierarchy 
- Dean
- PG Cord.
- Head of Department
- Staff Members

Now each of them have different roles.
**The problem.**
It is possible for the same individual to be the Head of Department and Postgraduate Cordinator. My problem is this, if they log in, how do i make whether to log them in as Postgraduate cordinator or Head of Department.
As their queries are some how different.

for the PG cordinator he would only see postgraduate student in his department, for the Head of department he would see all students of his department.

**What i have tried**
I have tried to give the highest role to a user e.g if you are the Head of department (H.O.D) and PG co-coordinator since the PG Co-ordinator is above H.O.D, I log you in as PG Cord.

However, their query parameters are not the same. For example as a H.O.D in fetch student in your department, my query string requires a department as a parameter. while for the PG Cord. department is not required

2. On a second thought i tried to log a user in and immediately after that redirect them to a page where they would select how they want to be logged_in. base on their roles. That way my user session is only complete when user have specify how they want to be logged_in. But i don't know if its the best way the go about it or if there are better ways

Comment: _how do i make whether to log them in as Postgraduate cordinator.._ give them the option too choose 1 role?

Comment: @B001ᛦ I mean should i allow them select the way they should log in. off course that is for people that have multiple roles.

Comment: _I mean should i allow them..._ This is what I told you in my first comment

Answer (score 0):

Some sites solve this problem by asking for a role right at the login screen.

```
username: [        ]
pasword:  [        ]
Role:     [Staff Members   V] <-- Dropdown, with the most common option pre-selected.

[Log in]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution #1: A **role** table where each rights are represented by a tiny-integer column (1, 0). They will be like "can_add_students" "can_view_students" or something like that.

Solution #2: Create a **role** table and a **permissions** table. The permissions table will have have a permission, a value and a parent role. This makes it more versatile and less messy to look at.

Solution #3: Probably the best but also the hardest is to implement [OAuth 2.0](https://oauth.net/2/) since it is exactly what you're describing. It is also secured, an industry standard. On the downside, the learning curve maybe a bit steep if you're still asking this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a role table. and i also have a staff_role where i store staffid and role_id. However what then happens when they have to view different category of students?